# Stuck on creating simple javascript object for mongodb query

Tags: javascript, mongodb

Sorry this should be so simple but I just cannot find the answer. I am trying to create a filter in code that exclude fields for documents from a mongodb collection. The filter should like this:

```
{'Group': 'question'},{Group: 0, Order: 0}
```

To get the first part I have used:

```
var myfilter = {};
myfilter[fieldname] = filterValue;
```

Which produces {'Group': 'question'} - but I cannot fathom how to add the extra ",{Group: 0, Order: 0}" to the end of this object.

Comment: What is the structure of your document?

Comment: It is used node routing: the code line is:      languageData.paginate(myfilter, req.query.page, req.query.limit, function(err, pageCount, mydata, itemCount) {

Answer (score 0):

`{Group: 0, Order: 0}` is a separate field-selection object that's passed as the second parameter to `find`.

For example:

```
var myfilter = {};
myfilter[fieldname] = filterValue;
var fields = {Group: 0, Order: 0};
coll.find(myfilter, fields, callback);
```

Comment: thanks but cannot get to accept coding, it worked in db.find() method but not in paginate - perhaps its the limitation of the pagination code

Comment: @user2942970 paginate isn't part of MongoDB; is that part of another library?  It would have been good to provide that detail in your question.

Comment: Yes sorry about that I am using mongoose-paginate library - it did not occur to me that the restriction was there - it is not a big problem I can exclude the fields in the schema instead - I just thought it was my lack of ability to join objects that was the problem.  Not sure as to how to close this question!

Comment: @user2942970 It's probably best to just delete the question.